# How to select different template depending on different angular js route value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a route like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/test/item/:item', {
            templateUrl: '/test/test.html'
            , controller: 'TestController'
        });
```

Now I want to load different templateUrl depending on different :item value, How do I do it in angularJS?

for example:

```
$routeProvider.when('/test/item/:1', {
            templateUrl: '/test/test1.html'
            , controller: 'TestController'
        });
$routeProvider.when('/test/item/:2', {
            templateUrl: '/test/test2.html'
            , controller: 'TestController'
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[templateUrl](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) can be a function as well and you get the first argument will be route params:

So you can do something like this:-

```
  $routeProvider.when('/test/item/:item', {
        templateUrl: function(param){
          return '/test/test' + param.name + '.html'
          /*if(param.name === 'somevalue'){
            return someurl;
          }
          return someotherurl;*/
        }
        , controller: 'TestController'
    });
```

> templateUrl – {string=|function()=} – path or function that returns a path to an html template that should be used by ngView.
>
> If templateUrl is a function, it will be called with the following parameters:
>
> {Array.} - route parameters extracted from the current $location.path() by applying the current route